# Unable to fit ARIMA to Time Series data

Tags: r, arima

I am working on the `daily_total_female_birth` dataset. However, I am unable to deploy ARIMA and unable to interpret the error message to diagnose the problem.

```r
acf(diff(log(DFB)))
pacf(diff(log(DFB)))
DFBfit<-arima(log(DFB),c(8,1,0),seasonal = list(order=c(8,1,0),period=12))
```

> Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian =
>   TRUE,  : initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: Reducing the order p of the seasonal and non-seasonal part of the arima, the code works with no errors.